# How can I access an element inside a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pytube

I want to be able to access totalResults from these dictionaries:
but I don't know how, I got this using Youtube playlist API key and Playlist ID, what I want to achieve is to get the total numbers of a playlist, and the value is stored in totalResults

```
 {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
      "etag": "-iic8jV4VirXOAQIXmRXGZQAoCs",
      "nextPageToken": "EAAaATA",
      "items": [],
      "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 6,
        "resultsPerPage": 0
      }
    }
```

Page link : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id&maxResults=0&playlistId=PLh9R-kdGXNL4re22eMuWzQkapepohLWEu&key=AIzaSyAMWYbTQqtGHobV5zP1fh1DFEYKKRokalk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just navigate throught the nested keys till you reach desired key-value.

Try this:

```
initial_dict = {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
      "etag": "-iic8jV4VirXOAQIXmRXGZQAoCs",
      "nextPageToken": "EAAaATA",
      "items": [],
      "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 6,
        "resultsPerPage": 0
      }
    }

total_result = initial_dict["pageInfo"]["totalResults"]

print(total_result)
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Cheers :)

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if you feel this is the answer to your question. :)